# Minicom missing 0x00 output from Xbee

Tags: serial, xbee

I connected my Raspberry Pi to an Xbee module and used minicom to read data from it. All the data is read out fine except that it missing 0x00 strings.

For example, if Xbee sends out data in HEX stream

```
7E 00 92 00 3A 55 00 01 00 01 77 00 3E 8A
```

This is for illustrating the issue only. The data format for specific Xbee data type `92` is not necessarily correct. But I only receive the data from minicom...

```
7E 92 3A 55 01 01 77 3E 8A
```

All the "00" ones are lost. I searched the Internet and could not find the cause or solution (say, figuration change) for fix.

Does anyone have any idea?

*By the way, the Xbee output to X-CTU is fine without issue. But minicom can not output HEX stream and there's no other better Linux serial terminal seems to be available either. How did I accomplish this? Well, you help me my issue, I will tell you how I did it.*

Comment: have you tried to pipe your serial output to hexdump, like "cat /dev/ttyXXX | hexdump" and see if you still have your zeros there?

Comment: Whatever your way of reading the values is the 00 is just getting ignored because whatever is parsing it thinks is not a value, like null or empty. That is the only thing I can think off.

Answer (score 1):

I have since abandoned minicom software as there's a defect there.

I used `miniterm.c` and compiled it which works fine.

I wanted the program to run in the background on the Raspberry Pi and I did not know how to modify the c program with system call fork(). So eventually I took the source `terminos.c` as reference and modified it. I am successfully receiving the solar panel output (voltage, current, light sensor and temp sensor) through Xbee and charting the parameters.

Now I am gaining a deeper understanding of the solar voltage out vs sunrise/sunset time and sunlight lux intensity.

Comment: Congratulations. Sometimes projects like these have these stupid hurdles to overcome. I hope your project will be a long term success and maybe your data can help somebody in the future :) `keep information free`